# ArgumentError: unknown keyword: :service (ArgumentError) from active_storage.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I am upgrading my ruby application to 3.2.2 version and getting this error from zeitwerk:check:

```
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: :service (ArgumentError)
/home/asd/app/config/initializers/active_storage.rb:5:in `has_one_attached'
```

active_storage.rb:

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  # Provides the class-level DSL for declaring that an Active Record model has attached blobs.
  ActiveStorage::Attached::Model.module_eval do
    class_methods do
      def has_one_attached(name, dependent: :purge_later, acl: :public)
        generated_association_methods.class_eval <<-CODE, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
          def #{name}
            @active_storage_attached_#{name} ||= ActiveStorage::Attached::One.new("#{name}", self, acl: "#{acl}")
          end
          def #{name}=(attachable)
            attachment_changes["#{name}"] =
              if attachable.nil?
                ActiveStorage::Attached::Changes::DeleteOne.new("#{name}", self)
              else
                ActiveStorage::Attached::Changes::CreateOne.new("#{name}", self, attachable, acl: "#{acl}")
              end
          end
        CODE

        has_one :"#{name}_attachment", -> { where(name: name) }, class_name: "ActiveStorage::Attachment", as: :record, inverse_of: :record, dependent: :destroy
        has_one :"#{name}_blob", through: :"#{name}_attachment", class_name: "ActiveStorage::Blob", source: :blob

        scope :"with_attached_#{name}", -> { includes("#{name}_attachment": :blob) }

        after_save { attachment_changes[name.to_s]&.save }

        after_commit(on: %i[ create update ]) { attachment_changes.delete(name.to_s).try(:upload) }

        ActiveRecord::Reflection.add_attachment_reflection(
          self,
          name,
          ActiveRecord::Reflection.create(:has_one_attached, name, nil, { dependent: dependent }, self)
        )
      end

      def has_many_attached(name, dependent: :purge_later, acl: :public)
        ...
      end
    end
  end

  ActiveStorage::Blob.class_eval do
    def service_url(expires_in: ActiveStorage.service_urls_expire_in, disposition: :inline, filename: nil, **options)
      filename = ActiveStorage::Filename.wrap(filename || self.filename)
      expires_in = false if metadata[:acl] == 'public'

      service.url key, expires_in: expires_in, filename: filename, content_type: content_type_for_service_url,
                  disposition: forced_disposition_for_service_url || disposition, **options
    end

    def upload_without_unfurling(io)
      service.upload key, io, checksum: checksum, **service_metadata.merge(acl: metadata[:acl])
    end
  end
...
```

The service is set in development.rb as: `config.active_storage.service = :local` and it defined in storage.yml

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

I couldn't figure out what is missing and couldn't find a similar issue.
Ruby: 3.2.2
Rails: 7.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added service to the method as below and the error is gone:

```
def has_one_attached(name, dependent: :purge_later, acl: :public, service: :service)
```